# ASP.NET - ViewState: empty placeholder generates view state

Tags: asp.net, viewstate, asp.net-4.0

On my web-page I have PlaceHolder, not controls are loaded into it.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderStatMain" runat="server">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

I am looking the ViewState generated for the page, it is the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJLTg1NDkyNTUzD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIND2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPZBYCZg9kFgJmD2QWBmYPFQEYL3N0YXRfc3RhZGl1bS9sZWFndWVfV0VGZAIBDxUBGC9zdGF0X3N0YWRpdW0vbGVhZ3VlX0VFRmQCAg8VARgvc3RhdF9zdGFkaXVtL2xlYWd1ZV9GQ1VkZEuSBUr5LFL6WfCehNBJgjrq0GzwWCWN2qlU70V7LAAb" />
```

When I set EnableViewState to false:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderStatMain" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

The viewstate content was decreased significantly:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJLTg1NDkyNTUzZGTTn8Y28VwmpE/K7yPPkLFvhrqMdU8THijFW/BMFzk0tQ==" />
```

Question: how to remove 'useless' viewstate content without disabling viewstate for placeholder himself (I would like other control loaded into placeholder to has viewstate)?

Is it possible at all?

Any thought are welcome!

P.S. I am using ASP.NET 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ASP.Net 4.0 you can disable the viewstate for the page with the [ViewStateMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.viewstatemode.aspx) parameter, and enable it for the controls which need it. Label1 will have viewstate and Label2 will not since it inherits the Disabled state from the page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs"
    ViewStateMode="Disabled" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>View State Demo in ASP.NET 4.0</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <div>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="One" ViewStateMode="Enabled"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Two"></asp:Label> <br /><br />      
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="PostBack" />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you suggestion is to disable ViewState for placeholder but if some controls will need it - i will need to enable it explicitly for particular controls. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, your other option is what we had before, disable it for all who don´t need it. Another route is to create an MVC app instead, which is stateless and don´t use ViewState. But using MVC is a different style of creating applications. You can also use tricks to store the viewstate on the server or compress it to save space, if that´s your concern.

Comment: MVC is not an option... I have a web site that is not feasible to be re-written on MVC. And there are not control inside of PlaceHolder, so there are nothing to disable except of placeholder himself. Furtunately, application is recompiled under asp.net 4.0, so I can go ahead with this suggestion. But other (if any) are also welcome!

Comment: @Budda: What is the problem with having the viewstate turned on for all controls? What are you trying to accomplish? You might want to check out http://mikemason.ca/blog/2008/11/compressing-viewstate/ and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MovingViewStateToTheSessionObjectAndMoreWrongheadedness.aspx

Comment: I will answer with another question: what is good in useless information that causes performance/traffic issues? Another answer: Microsoft's recommendations to disable ViewState when it is not required

Comment: There is no use in useless information, but the framework developers cannot know what is useful or not. Instead of creating special code when implementing the placeholder control, it inherits from the same base as other webcontrols, and thus have viewstate. Nothing is perfect, but giving a placeholder viewstate is a small cost when it can inherit many other properties. At least in my opinion. All special code requires more maintenance and possible more bugs.